# Why does IE submit a POST request when I click <a><button/></a>?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http

I've got a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {% for field in form %}
            {% partial "partials/field.html" field=field %}
        {% endfor %}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input name="save" type="submit" value="{% if is_new_entry %}Save{% else %}Update{% endif %}" class="submit" />
                {% if not is_new_entry %}
                    <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete" class="submit" />
                {% endif %}
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url dealership-entry %}"><button class="submit">New</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want that "New" button just to submit a GET request back to that href. This works fine in FF (albeit it puts a stupid underline behind the button which I had to hide), but in IE it actually submits the form!

What's the easiest way to do what I want? I was thinking about closing off the form, then putting a new form with just the one "New" button and put the "href" in the action instead, but I don't think that'd be valid XHTML anymore, because the `</form>` needs to go after `</table>`.

I don't want to use JavaScript.

Comment: Have you considered **not putting a submit button there** if you don't want it to submit the form when it is clicked?

Comment: @jalf, that was my first thought, but then I worried that I was just being churlish. **+1**.

Comment: @jalf: stylistically, I want it to appear exactly there, inside that `<td>`. How do you suppose I rearrange the HTML to achieve that?

Comment: PS: That's what the "I was thinking about closing off the form..." paragraph was about, so yes, I did consider that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You put a submit button but apparently don't want it to submit. So *what* do you want to appear "exactly there"? The submit button? Or just *a* button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button is not just a 'stylistic' object, but also a functional one.

What you appear to need is an anchor tag (A) styled to appear to be a button. You can do that with CSS alone, and very convincingly with CSS+Images for button states.

The button tag inside the anchor tag is fairly nonstandard (and may be technically invalid), so that's why you aren't getting consistent behavior.

Comment: Actually, button inside an anchor seems to be valid markup, but it seems logical that it should override the anchor's behaviour. I agree that the problem here is button used instead of CSS.

Comment: @zvonimir It is not valid. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#interactive-content

Comment: Yup, zvonimir; I just did a check against an XHTML1.0 validator I have, and a BUTTON inside an A did not trigger a warning (whereas nesting an A directly inside an LI, for example, does).

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it's valid, it doesn't work in IE (as usual). @Andrew: You propose a reasonable solution, but not one I like.

Comment: Fair enough :) I think without JavaScript and without tearing up your form, it's the easiest way. Actually, I think it's even easier than those options myself.. hehe.. I've done links-as-buttons like this myself before.

Answer (score 1):

Is this even valid? to put a button inside a link? A button should post or get depending on what the form does.

Here you have

```
<form method="post">
```

so it will post.

Maybe use something like jquery to create a link to post?

should be:

```
<form action="postform.php" method="post">
```

I believe you're not suppose to style buttons as this is an OS styling thing.

Comment: I thought the whole point of `<button>` was for stylistic purposes; for use outside a form. Apparently, it can be used for either. I don't see how making the button a link is different than making an image a link. Regardless, I'd prefer not to use JS.

Comment: Why should a `button` *not* be styled? @Mark, so just use a styled link, rather than nesting a `button`. It's much easier, and more reliable. Not to mention valid (x)html.

Comment: @David: Because I want it to look exactly like my other 2 buttons?

Comment: @Mark, but it's invalid to have a `button` as a descendant of an `a` element. You can style the buttons *and* a link with exactly the same css if similarity is all you're after.

Comment: @David: I prefer the OS defaults... plus, styling buttons isn't nicely supported across browsers.

Comment: @Mark, if you want to keep the OS defaults then you're going to have to live with the OS/browser defaults. Or use js to prevent that particular button from submitting the form.

Comment: @David: Eh? Your first sentence doesn't make sense... that's exactly what I want..which is why I said it. And JS isn't necessary, I've already proven that.

Comment: @Mark you're right. I was thinking of an input like mentioned above. Been a while since i touched a form. But i still don't agree with styling a button. As you mentioned and from what i remember, all the browsers don't agree with each other. Thats why i like to use javascript to make a link post.

Answer (score 0):

your method is post, would that have anything to do with it? i might be reading u wrong

All browsers seem to submit a form when a button with a submit class with it

Comment: All browsers submit a form (assuming no js intervention) when a `button` of `type="submit"` is clicked. The class, for css reasons, shouldn't really have any effect on the action taken by the `onClick` event.

Comment: he doesnt have a type=submit on it, and its submitting, sooooo idk

Comment: @Ascheer: That's because (most) browsers have a default of type=submit. And yes, I think you're reading me wrong. The other 2 buttons *are* supposed to POST the form, but I was hoping the "new" button would ignore that and work like a link.

Comment: just take it out of the form then?

Comment: @Ascheer: How am I supposed to submit my form then?!

Comment: javascript haha, honestly what you are trying to do would really be best suited for an ajax post or something

Comment: Now you're just being ridiculous! This is supposed to be a dead-simple form. This isn't even apart of the main site, just some admin junk :P

Comment: Being honest. It would be best suited to use javascript with it

Answer (score 0):

Always specify the type attribute for the button. The default type for Internet Explorer is "button", while in other browsers (and in the W3C specification) it is "submit".

Comment: Just read that, but it doesn't help. It appears that IE8 is following the spec now, because by default it actually does *submit* the form. Changing it to "button" makes it do *nothing*, even when wrapped in a link, or putting the link inside.

Answer (score 0):

My present solution is to make the "New" button into an actual `<input type=submit>` button and handle it with a redirect on the backend, rather than fighting with the HTML and validity.